# Dell XPS 400 diagnostic lights 3 and 4

Tags: memory-error

I have a Dell XPS 400, 3 GB of RAM (1GB x2 and 512MB x2). I powered it on this morning and got the 3 and 4 diag lights; monitor shows no input. Dell docs say that "memory modules are detected, but a memory failure has occurred". As suggested, I went through the process of removing the modules one by one, even purchased new modules, but the lights are still there. Any clue what it might be? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could be a busted motherboard...or CPU, as sometimes the CPUs have memory controllers.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with either the processor, memory controller, PCB traces to the memory banks, or the banks themselves.

Comment: Wow, this place is about as awesome as stackoverflow.com... Any way I can run some sort of diagnostic myself - Dell wants $50 for it? Or would it make more sense to just go out and purchase a new motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

Check the motherboard for swollen/bulging capacitors.

http://www.capacitorlab.com/visible-failures/

If they show signs, the motherboard needs replaced, or have someone skilled in soldering to replace the bad caps.